# CRM Dynamics Performance / Timeout issue

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

We have Microsoft Dynamics 365 (CRM) on premise version.

This instance is used by around 100 users and there are 15+ custom applications written in .Net, which consumes CRM Web service to perform CRUD operations.

For fetching data there are direct SQL select statements and NO Web service existence across the custom applications. Data size is also not much high, few plugins and workflows defined in CRM system. Since long everything has worked but suddenly from last 2-3 months we have started seeing performance issues where end users are seeing slowness, or screen taking long time than expected to load controls, or Timeout errors.

This issue is not constant its an intermittent issue and it happens in business hours (PST/EST)

I wanted to know if there is any way to capture the logs about the issue in CRM, any, way in CRM where I can go and refer the log information or error traces which will help me to get the bottom of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the old `tools/diagnostics/diag.aspx` page should still work on-prem.

Just append that path to your Dynamics URL, e.g.: `https://myOrg.mydomain.com/tools/diagnostics/diag.aspx`

When you click Run it will generate some stats about the network and form performance.

[image: screenshot]

Dynamics also has diagnostics tracing capabilities built in (or at least it used to - haven't tried recently.) [This article](https://kishored4.wordpress.com/2017/04/15/enable-tracing-for-dynamics-crm-on-premise/) has instructions on that.

Here's a summary (unconfirmed & untested)
On the CRM Server

1. Open registry (run  regedit)
2. Navigate to  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSCRM
3. Add new keys:

Name: TraceEnabled
Type: DWORD
Value: 1

Name: TraceDirectory
Type: String
Value: C:\CRMTrace

Name: TraceRefresh
Type: DWORD
Value: 99

5. Create the folder "CRMTrace" in C directory
6. Reset IIS (Run CMD as administrator >> execute this “iisreset” command )

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-818e8774-e123-4995-417d-7ea02395c6d0) has more, including PowerShell instructions.

Back in the day there was a desktop app called the Diagnostics Tool that allowed you to turn the logging on and off.
[image: screenshot2]

**Also, please note that if you accidentally leave the logging on, it can fill up the C: drive and crash the server!**